# Resizing and zipping image streams using archiver and sharp

Tags: node.js, node-archiver

I'm trying to download some images, resize them, zip them, and serve from an endpoint using streams.  I'm using [*sharp*](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) for the resizing and [*archiver*](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver) for the zipping.  I can get these packages to work on their own but not together.

Here's some example code:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const archiver = require('archiver');
const sharp = require('sharp');
const request = require('request');

function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const imageStreams = [request('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png'), request('https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdUwb.png'), request('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d55j.png')]

    const zip = archiver('zip');
    zip.on('error', e => console.log('zip error: ', e.message));
    zip.on('entry', entry => console.log('appended ', entry.name));

    resolve(zip);

    process.nextTick(() => {
      console.log('number of streams: ', imageStreams.length);

      imageStreams.map((stream, j) => {
        const resize = sharp().resize(100, 100);

        return stream.pipe(resize);
      })
      .forEach((resizedImageStream, i) => {
        console.log('appending ', i, ' to zip');
        zip.append(resizedImageStream, { name: `${i}.png` });
      });

      console.log('finalizing zip');
      zip.finalize();
    });
  });
}

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({port: 3000});

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: (request, reply) => {
    foo().then(zip => reply(zip));
  }
})
server.start();
```

Run it with:

`npm init --yes && npm install hapi archiver sharp request && node index.js`

This will create an endpoint at http://localhost:3000 which will fail to stream the zip file to the response.

The following will each make the download work:

- Removing the sharp transformation
- Replacing sharp with imagemagick-stream
- Only handling a single image, i.e. `imageStreams.slice(0, 1)`

But I can't get it to work with multiple images and resizing at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the sharp library, which has now been fixed [here](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/671)